# Equivalance of instanceof for CLOS? How to check if instance is inherited from another object?

Tags: inheritance, common-lisp, clos

```
CL-USER> (defclass a () ())
CL-USER> (defclass b (a) ())
CL-USER> (make-instance 'b)
#<STANDARD-CLASS B>
```

What predicate function can I call on my instance b, which returns T if it was inherited from a? In the vein of:

```
CL-USER> (instanceof 'a *)
T
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Class names are also type names, so:

```
(typep * 'a)
```

See *Integrating Types and Classes*: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/04_cg.htm

Or you could do this:

```
(defmethod is-an-a-p ((x a))
  t)
(defmethod is-an-a-p ((x t))
  nil)
```