# Checking parent class of an object

Tags: inheritance, lisp, common-lisp, clos

I would like to know a way how to check if an object is of certain class, or derived from it. E.g.:

```
(defclass a nil
  nil)

(defclass b (a)
  nil)

(defparameter *foo* (make-instance 'b))

(my-function *foo* 'a) ; => t
(my-function *foo* 'b) ; => t
```

Alternatively, a function that returns list of all base classes for a given object (or class) would be also appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalance of instanceof for CLOS? How to check if instance is inherited from another object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151569/equivalance-of-instanceof-for-clos-how-to-check-if-instance-is-inherited-from-a)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`typep`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_typep.htm):

```
CL-USER 4 > (typep *foo* 'a)
T

CL-USER 5 > (typep *foo* 'b)
T
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MOP's (MetaObject Protocol) `class-direct-superclasses'

Quickload the library closer-mop and use `class-direct-superclasses' like so:

```
CL-USER> (closer-mop:class-direct-superclasses (find-class 'number))
(#<BUILT-IN-CLASS T>)
CL-USER>
```

If you have an instance of a class, you can do

```
CL-USER> (let ((table (make-instance 'test-table-2)))
           (class-direct-superclasses (class-of table)))
(#<STANDARD-CLASS STANDARD-OBJECT>)} 
CL-USER>
```

A possible gotcha (documented in the library):  If you DEFPACKGE that :USEs closer-mop, instead of using CL, :USE closer-common-lisp